# 'Primary key not found' when scaffolding Razor view (EF Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, reverse-engineering, razor-pages

I'm trying to create a Razor List View using the model and the context of an SQL View I succesfully scaffolded before as it was a Table.
When trying to scaffold the controller I get the 'Primary key not found' error message.

Model:

```
using System;


namespace PSWebase2.Models
{
    public partial class ViewCalibraRmm
    {
        public string CódigoDoRmm { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DataUc { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DataPc { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Context already has the "HasNoKey" in its properties:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Entity < ViewCalibraRmm > (entity => {
            entity.HasNoKey();

            entity.ToView("View_Calibra_RMM");

            entity.Property(e => e.CódigoDoRmm)
                .HasColumnName("Código_do_RMM")
                .HasMaxLength(66);

            entity.Property(e => e.DataPc)
                .HasColumnName("DataPC")
                .HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.Property(e => e.DataUc)
                .HasColumnName("DAtaUC")
                .HasColumnType("datetime");
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaffold the controller need primary key, because Entity Framework needs to know the key to keep track on the object when you make an update or delete operation.

> Use the scaffolding tool to produce Create, Read, Update, and Delete
> (CRUD) pages for the movie model.

refer to:[document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-movie-pages)

[image]

But Keyless entity types

> Are never tracked for changes in the DbContext and therefore are never
> inserted, updated or deleted on the database.

refer to [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations#keyless-entity-types-characteristics)

So,when trying to scaffold the controller , get the 'Primary key not found' error message.

You can use  the EF Core Migrations feature to create the database. Migrations is a set of tools that create and update a database to match the data model.

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate
Update-Database
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, although manually creating the controller and then the view on my own did the trick, I finally understood why my initial approach didn't work.